# Implement calender view in Android

Tags: java, android, events, calendar, android-custom-view

I need to implement calender view in android. I have successfully implemented using `<CalenderView>`. In my scenario when I select date I will take the selected date and send it to my server. But in this when I want to go to previous or next month I need to scroll and go to next month, while scrolling any one date is selected. so I need to implement previous and next month like the image below

[image]

Is it possible to implement this previous and next month using default calenderview.

Comment: If you want to select one date,you may use date_picker instead of calender view

Comment: I would recommend you to use caldroid, it has all the features you want: Check this out

https://github.com/roomorama/Caldroid